# React-native NetInfo with promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, react-native

I have a modified code in react-native for fetching data with server, that works fine. I want to add NetInfo to always check before fetching if telephone has connection to internet. Is it posible inside promise? How to connect this async function to my code?

```
'use strict';

var MAX_WAITING_TIME = 30000

var processStatus = function (response) {
    // status "0" to handle local files fetching (e.g. Cordova/Phonegap etc.)
    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 0 || response.status === 201 || response.status === 422 || response.status === 302 ) {
        return Promise.resolve(response)
    } else if(response.status === 413) {
         return Promise.reject(alert(____mobile.connection_error.large_file))
    } else {
        //return Promise.reject(alert("Process status: "+JSON.stringify(response )))
        return Promise.reject(alert(____mobile.connection_error.top));
        console.log("Process status: "+JSON.stringify(response ));
    }
};

var parseJson = function (response) {
    return response.json();
};

var getWrappedPromise = function () {
    var wrappedPromise = {},
            promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                wrappedPromise.resolve = resolve;
                wrappedPromise.reject = reject;
            });
    wrappedPromise.then = promise.then.bind(promise);
    wrappedPromise.catch = promise.catch.bind(promise);
    wrappedPromise.promise = promise;// e.g. if you want to provide somewhere only promise, without .resolve/.reject/.catch methods
    return wrappedPromise;
};

/* @returns {wrapped Promise} with .resolve/.reject/.catch methods */
var getWrappedFetch = function () {
    var wrappedPromise = getWrappedPromise();
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);// arguments to Array

    fetch.apply(null, args)// calling original fetch() method
        .then(function (response) {
            wrappedPromise.resolve(response);
        }, function (error) {
           // wrappedPromise.reject(alert("Fetch status: " + error));
            wrappedPromise.reject(____mobile.connection_error.top);
            console.log("Fetch status: " + error);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            wrappedPromise.catch(error);
        });
    return wrappedPromise;
};

/**
 * Fetch JSON by url
 * @param { {
 *  url: {String},
 *  [cacheBusting]: {Boolean}
 * } } params
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
var postJSON = function (params) {
    var headers1 = {}
    if (params.json){
        headers1 = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } 

    if (params.headersIn){
        headers1 = params.headersIn
    }

   var methodTmp = 'POST'

    if (params.methodIn) {
        methodTmp = params.methodIn
    }
    console.log(methodTmp)
    var wrappedFetch = getWrappedFetch(
        params.cacheBusting ? params.url + '?' + new Date().getTime() : params.url,
        {
            method: methodTmp,//'POST',// optional, "GET" is default value
            headers: headers1,

            body: params.send_data
        });

    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        wrappedFetch.reject(alert(____mobile.connection_error.timeout, ____mobile.connection_error.check_connection));// reject on timeout
    }, MAX_WAITING_TIME);

    return wrappedFetch.promise// getting clear promise from wrapped
        .then(function (response) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            return response;
        })
        .then(processStatus)
        .then(parseJson);
};



module.exports = postJSON;
```

What would be the bast way to implement:  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch() so fetched would only worked when there is internet connection?

EDIT: 
I want to use:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch()
```

Yeah I have to rewrite this code, not to use getWrappedPromise and now I think is good time for it.

EDIT2: Ok I refactored this code fragment, hope its better. Any comments welcome. I tested and I'm not sure if I still need this NetInfo.isConnected.fetch(). Now there is no errors where there is no connection or am I missing something? 
New code:

```
var processStatus = function (response) {
    if (response == undefined) {
        return null
    }
    // status "0" to handle local files fetching (e.g. Cordova/Phonegap etc.)
    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 0 || response.status === 201 || response.status === 422 || response.status === 302 ) {
        return Promise.resolve(response)
    } else if(response.status === 413) {
         return Promise.reject(alert(____mobile.connection_error.large_file))
    } else {
        //return Promise.reject(alert("Process status: "+JSON.stringify(response )))
        console.log("Process status: "+JSON.stringify(response ));
        return Promise.reject(alert(____mobile.connection_error.top));
    }
};

var parseJson = function (response) {
    if (response == undefined) {
        return null
    }
    return response.json();
};

var postJSON = function (params) {
    var headers1 = {}
    if (params.json){
        headers1 = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } 

    if (params.headersIn){
        headers1 = params.headersIn
    }

   var methodTmp = 'POST'

    if (params.methodIn) {
        methodTmp = params.methodIn
    }
    console.log(methodTmp)

    var fetchPromise = fetch(params.cacheBusting ? params.url + '?' + new Date().getTime() : params.url,
        {
            method: methodTmp,//'POST',// optional, "GET" is default value
            headers: headers1,

            body: params.send_data
        })// calling original fetch() method
        .then(function (response) {
            return response;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Fetch status: " + error);
            return fetch
        }).then(processStatus)
        .then(parseJson);


    // timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    //     wrappedFetch.reject(alert(____mobile.connection_error.timeout, ____mobile.connection_error.check_connection));// reject on timeout
    // }, MAX_WAITING_TIME);

    return fetchPromise
};
```

Comment: `getWrappedPromise` - ouch! The deferred pattern was deprecated for a reason. Why not just use the `Promise` constructor properly?

Comment: `getWrappedFetch` is just wrong on so many levels. What's its purpose? Just use `fetch` directly.

Comment: "*How to connect this async function to my code?*" - which function are you talking about? Please post it, even if it is not yet connected properly to your code.

Comment: Edited my question and posted function I want to add. And it's a good time to rewrite it and get rid of wrappedPromise I think

Comment: What does `isConncted.fetch` return, and what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: It returns in React-Native if mobile device is connected to internet via Wi-Fi or GSM/4G etc. I want to determine first if there is connection and if so, call my fetch function to communicate with server.